# Reports seems to be very slow in the new Spring 19

Tags: reporting

We have tried a bunch of reports after Salesforce upgrading to Spring 19. It seems that reports with more than 500 rows have a significant slowness in lightning experience.

I am aware of this known issue here: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000BMntQAG&title=lightning-reports-enhanced-run-page-slow-performance-when-formula-fields-with-images-and-long-text-area-fields-are-displayed . However, even without formula with long text or images we are still experiencing slowness and sometimes even a hang page. Any one has an idea about what has caused that or a probable walk around?

Comment: On which browser you are? If you are in IE, it is obvious. I would also recommend you to clear all your cache, browser history and reload the browser once.

Comment: @sanketkumar I am on Chrome. And it is not just me. We have a bunch of individuals tried with this and even at different places in the world. And pretty much got similar results

Comment: When spring 19 enrolled in Sandboxes, many of the standard buttons stopped working, so i removed the cache, cleared the browsing history and it started working. I was also in Chrome wth latest version

Comment: @sanketkumar tried. Still really slow

Comment: This in an issue. Tried Chrome, Safari, Firefox on mac, windows, different pcs. Reports are working just terrible. Something is completely broken

Comment: Not an answer just want to confirm we are seeing very very slow report loading as well. Many users have cleared their cache and reloaded the browsers, all up to date and either Chrome or Safari. Our Admin has logged a Case with Salesforce this morning.